# MySQL - How to get record count for each day of last 7 days?

Tags: mysql

What I am trying to do is to get the record count for each day of the last 7 days,
Let's say I have 3 records today, 4 records yesterday, 2 records two days ago, etc.

I'd like to have something like that:

```
[12/06/2021] 1
[11/06/2021] 4
[10/06/2021] 3
[09/06/2021] 6
[08/06/2021] 7
[07/06/2021] 2
[06/06/2021] 7
```

(Or get only the count, it's OK too.)

I have a field - message_datetime that saves the datetime.

Is there a way to do this in one query?

What I've done:

```
select CAST(message_datetime AS DATE),count(message_datetime) from messages group by CAST(message_datetime AS DATE) WHERE message_datetime
```

It worked but I wanted the last 7 days. Thanks

Comment: add the query that you have already tried from your end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was waiting for you to post your own effort, but since somebody has already "jumped the gun" and started to post answers, so:

Assuming the name of the table is `my_table`, then try:

```
select date(message_datetime) as message_date, count(*) as cnt from my_table
where datediff(curdate(), date(message_datetime)) < 7
group by date(message_datetime)
order by date(message_datetime) desc
```

**Update**

Following the Strawberry's suggestion, here is an updated query that should be more performant if `message_datetime` is an indexed column:

```
select date(message_datetime) as message_date, count(*) as cnt from my_table
where message_date_time >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 6 day)
group by date(message_datetime)
order by date(message_datetime) desc
```

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Note that an option avoiding functions against indexed columns in the WHERE clause would be more efficient

Answer (score 0):

i have this table

```
desc t1;
```

[image]

with this datas

mysql> select* from t1;

[image]
now i do this

mysql> select day_date,count(day_date) from t1 group by (date(day_date));

[image]

Comment: `day_date` is not a `datetime` column (and it's the wrong name) and your SQL does not output the count for just the last 7 days.

Comment: i try to modify it.